# SQLite проверить существование строки в базе данных

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Как проверить присутствие строки в базе данных SQLite и если есть то обновлять какое то значение в строке?

Comment: `Как проверить присутствие строки` - запросом `SELECT [fieldset] FROM [tableset] WHERE [criteria]` и последующей проверкой количества отобранных записей. `если есть то обновлять` - это выполняется UPDATE-запросом, и при этом предварительная проверка не требуется, т.к. если нет отвечающих критериям записей, то и обновления не будет.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. просто  я хотел проверить для того чтобы при отсутствии строки она добавилась в базе данных а если есть то просто обновилась

Comment: В SQLite есть INSERT OR REPLACE (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) - его назначение как раз в том, чтобы попытаться вставить запись, а если какой-либо из уникальных индексов это не позволяет, то вместо вставки выполнить обновление конфликтующей записи.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4330694